# Error in Atomic stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

`InsertCity` stored procedure , to insert city name in database.
After successful insert, log who has done it (using `insertlog` stored procedure) .
These steps should be atomic.

This is my SQL Server Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [paycom].[InsertCity]
(
    @name nvarchar(50),
    @employeeID int
)

AS

Begin Atomic

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    declare @cityID int

    INSERT INTO City (CityName) VALUES (@name)
    select @cityID = Scope_IDentity()
    exec InsertLog @employeeID, @name, @cityID

    return @cityID
End
```

and I get this errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertCity, Line 15 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'SET'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   InsertCity, Line 23 Incorrect syntax near 'End'.

Any idea about?

**without begin atomic, it works properly!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really mean is to use a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql) and proper error handling.

And don't use RETURN to return values

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
Declare @cityID int;

Begin TRY

   BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO City (CityName) VALUES (@name)
    select @cityID = Scope_IDentity()
    exec InsertLog @employeeID, @name, @cityID

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @cityID;
End try
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

I doubt you really want to use in-memory OLTP etc

Answer (score 0):

> The following options are required with BEGIN ATOMIC: Required
>   Setting    TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL     LANGUAGE

https://msdn.microsoft.com/eu-es/library/dn452281(v=sql.120).aspx